# Maven/TestNG reports "Failures: 0" but then "There are test failures.", what's wrong?

Tags: maven-2, maven, testng, surefire

I'm using Maven 2.2.1 r801777, Surefire 2.7.1, TestNG 5.14.6, Java 1.6.0_11 on Win XP.

I have only one test class with one empty test method and in my pom I have just added TestNG dependency. When I execute `mvn test` it prints out:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.301 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to [...]\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

There is no error in test reports and with `-e` switch:

```
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to [...]\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to [...]\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.execute(SurefirePlugin.java:575)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
```

Any idea?

---

EDIT

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <name>sample</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description />

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The only class that I have:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals("a", "a");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you updated your imports in your test class. Furthermore have you done some Assert.assertEquals() etc. ? Have you tried to do mvn clean test?

Comment: Yes, I have done them all. In fact what I have described is after completely isolating the problem.

Comment: Can you post your pom here? Do the tests run inside IDE ?

Comment: I have added what ever I have in my project (a pom and a test class). I'm using Eclipse but currently doing mvn on command prompt.

Comment: Without that single test class I'm still getting "There are test failures."!!!

Comment: @khmarbaise I have the same problem with an empty maven/pom project! Do you have any idea?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just created simple example project with your pom file (Fixed some parts) and put it on [github](https://github.com/khmarbaise/testtestng) ...tested with Maven 2.2.1 and Maven 3.0.2 works perfect. The cause of the problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: That was crazy, the problem was that I had changed default cmd start path in regedit! Thanks for helping to nail down the problem.

Comment: What you missed where the version definition of the plugins (compile and surefire).

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the surefire plugin version (2.4.1 if you face the same issue) as follows and also specify the forkmode and useManifestOnlyJar values

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>none</forkMode><!-- 'none' is so we can debug -->
                <argLine>-enableassertions</argLine>
                <!--
                <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>
                        ${basedir}/src/main/resources/testng-none.xml
                    </suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```